# LaTeX templates

Tags: bibliographies, table-of-contents, languages

I am writing my thesis using LaTeX and it actually is the first time I use it. I am using some templates from my university but they are in Spanish and I want to write my work in English.

The reason of this message is that I am getting crazy with the indexes and the bibliography because, although I want the title of these chapters to be in English, they are written in Spanish. Of course I have tried to find out where the mistake is and even found some information on the Internet but it is not working out.

This is how I am managing the indexes:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}  

\listoffigures

  \newpage \thispagestyle{empty}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables}   
\listoftables

  \newpage \thispagestyle{empty}
```

But instead of List of figures/tables, the Spanish translation appears in the pdf.

On the other hand, this is how I managed the references:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}
```

Comment: What templete did you use?

Comment: @noemi: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Answer (score 2):

The section/chapter headings for list of tables/list of figures are usually stored in the macros `\listtablename` and `\listfigurename`, so `\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}` might set you up. If you use the `babel` package, you will have to do this *after* `\begin{document}`, or modify the parameters to `babel` so that no support for spanish is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first thing to look for is the `babel` package being used with `spanish`.

I also write documents in Spanish and English, and --for example-- what makes latex to write **Índice** instead of **Table of Contents** is the use of that package:

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```